# SelectAll in gridview using javascript on postback issue

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

i have a gridview which has a checkbox column. The header is of this column is a checkbox.

When it is checked all the values get checked and vice-verse.

I do this using javascript.

The problem is if i check it and perform any other event on the page which requires a postback the checked values disappear. I dont want them to disappear.

here is my code:

```
 <script  type="text/javascript">

 function checkAllBoxes() {

      //get total number of rows in the gridview and do whatever
      //you want with it..just grabbing it just cause
      var totalChkBoxes = parseInt('<%= GridView1.Rows.Count %>');
      var gvControl = document.getElementById('<%= GridView1.ClientID %>');

      //this is the checkbox in the item template...this has to be the same name as the ID of it
      var gvChkBoxControl = "Select_CheckBox";

      //this is the checkbox in the header template
      var mainChkBox = document.getElementById("chkBoxAll");

      //get an array of input types in the gridview
      var inputTypes = gvControl.getElementsByTagName("input");

      for (var i = 0; i < inputTypes.length; i++) {
          //if the input type is a checkbox and the id of it is what we set above
          //then check or uncheck according to the main checkbox in the header template             
          if (inputTypes[i].type == 'checkbox' && inputTypes[i].id.indexOf(gvChkBoxControl, 0) >= 0)
              inputTypes[i].checked = mainChkBox.checked;
      }
  }

  </script>

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField>
   <HeaderTemplate>
     <input id="chkBoxAll" type="checkbox" onclick="checkAllBoxes()"/>
   </HeaderTemplate>
   <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:CheckBox ID="Select_CheckBox" runat="server" />
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
 <!-- The rest of your rows here -->
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Make your checkbox a server-side control that uses the view state by adding `runat="server"`. It will then maintain its value across post backs.

```
<input id="chkBoxAll" type="checkbox" onclick="checkAllBoxes()" runat="server"/>
```

And change your JavaScript to select the id that ends in `chkBoxAll`. I use jQuery in the example below:

```
//this is the checkbox in the header template
var mainChkBox = $('input[id$="chkBoxAll"]');
```

However, if you sort your gridview rows or use paging, you will likely come across less friendly behavior.

Comment: I get this... error CS0103: The name 'chkBoxAll' does not exist in the current context

Comment: I edited it a minute ago. Do you have `<%= chkBoxAll.ClientID %>`?  I had forgot to add `ClientID` until my edit.

Comment: i keep getting the same error:  error CS0103: The name 'chkBoxAll' does not exist in the current context

Comment: maybe its in the gridview so it is noble to find it

Comment: Alright, I fixed it again. Add `clientidmode="static"` rather than use the client id. As you said, since it's in the GridView `<HeaderTemplate>`, it isn't recognized server side. You don't have to change your JavaScript at all.

Comment: i applied the change but now when i check select all nothing happens but when i check the individual checkboxes i get javascript error.. object expected.. this is vrazy man.. thanks for all the help though

Comment: I updated again to explain how to use jQuery to solve your issue once and for all. Obviously, you'll need to implement the jQuery framework.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3071/discussion-between-user175084-and-justin-satyr)